# Launch executables from Matlab in linux

Tags: bash, matlab, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to launch executables from within Matlab 2017a on Ubuntu 17.04, but even simple ones won't run properly. I tried launching the gnome-terminal with these three methods: `!gnome-terminal`, `system('gnome-terminal')`, or `unix('gnome-terminal')`

They all return an error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/python3: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

Or if I try to run `nautilus`

```
!nautilus
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.7)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcapnp-0.5.3.so)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircore.so.1)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircore.so.1)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.62.0)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.62.0)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.10)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.10)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.62.0)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.62.0)
nautilus: /media/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkj-0.5.3.so)
```

These commands work fine if I run them from an external terminal, and the `$PATH` is the same as in MATLAB. Could this be related to 32 vs. 64 bit issues?

My end goal was to launch an external terminal that would run a script and show me the output there:

```
!gnome-terminal -e 'bash run.sh' &
```

and allow the MATLAB script to continue. So if there's another way to accomplish this task that would also be useful/appreciated.

Comment: I'm running 2017b in Mint 18 and `!gnome-terminal` works. I'd guess that matlab is invoking things in python by default for some reason. Do you happen to remember if you had matlab rename its c libraries when you installed? I chose to do so.

Comment: I don't remember seeing that option, I will check. The errors returned by nautilus suggest that it's trying to use Matlab's C libraries instead of my system's?